# Why this code doesn't work in parallel python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, subprocess

I tried to use pp(Parallel Python) like this:

```
import glob
import subprocess
import pp


def run(cmd): 
    print cmd
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True) 

job_server = pp.Server()
job_server.set_ncpus(8)
jobs = []
for a_file in glob.glob("./*"): 
    cmd = "ls" 
    jobs.append(job_server.submit(run, (cmd,))) 
for j in jobs: 
    j()
```

But encountered such an error that subprocess.call is not a global name.

```
An error has occured during the function execution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pp-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/ppworker.py", line 90, in run
    __result = __f(*__args)
  File "<string>", line 3, in run
NameError: global name 'subprocess' is not defined
```

I've imported subprocess, why can't it be used here?

According to abarnert's suggestion, I changed my code to this:

```
import glob
import pp
def run(cmd): 
    print cmd
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True) 
job_server = pp.Server()
job_server.set_ncpus(8)
jobs = []
for a_file in glob.glob("./*"): 
    cmd = "ls" 
    jobs.append(job_server.submit(run, (cmd,),modules=("subprocess",))) 
for j in jobs: 
    j()
```

But it still doesn't work, it complains like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pp-1.6.1-py2.6.egg/pp.py", line 721, in _run_local
    job.finalize(sresult)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sresult' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: This new problem is completely different, and unrelated to your original one, and you should probably write a separate question for it. But briefly: PP jobs can't spawn new processes without causing all kinds of problems, and I don't know that anyone has a fix for that. On top of that, any problem that leads to the pipes breaking (which attempting to spawn new processes will cause) leads to that "sresult referenced before assignment" error, which is due to be fixed in a future release. You probably want to discuss this on the PP forums.

Comment: In particular, start here: http://www.parallelpython.com/component/option,com_smf/Itemid,29/topic,408.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation explains this pretty well, and each example shows you how to deal with it.

Among the params of the submit method is "modules - tuple with module names to import". Any modules you want to be available in the submitted job has to be listed here.

So, you can do this:

```
jobs.append(job_server.submit(run, (cmd,), (), ('subprocess',)))
```

Or this:

```
jobs.append(job_server.submit(run, (cmd,), modules=('subprocess',)))
```

Comment: yup.  it's explained in the very first example in the docs - http://www.parallelpython.com/content/view/17/31/

Comment: Thanks, abarnert, I changed my codes as your suggestion, but it encounters another error as what I added in my question..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, untested, but did you try:

```
from subprocess import call
```

Inside the 'run' function?

And then use "call" instead of "subprocess.call" ?  That would make 'call' local to the function but accessible.

Comment: hi, I tried that, but it just complains: ``NameError: global name 'call' is not defined``

Comment: Put the import inside the function; revised answer.